# SQL Server transactions and parameterized queries from Access 2007 (DAO? ADO?)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am being forced to port a SQL load script to VBA in Access 2007 where I read flatfiles and then insert into SQL Server (using ODBC and parameterized query strings). Can someone post a full example of how to use either DAO querydef or ADO so that my inserts are executed in a single transaction on the SQL Server? I not need linked tables, file is read and all transforms are done in VBA prior to insert and done using stored procs and triggers in SQL Server after the load. But I do need to be able to rollback my multiple-inserts if there is an ODBC error.

None of the other stackoverflow posts I've found make much sense to me; all I know is that "ODBCDirect workspaces" are not supported in Access 2007. Does using ADO and BeginTrans make the most sense for me?

Comment: What ahve you tried so far? Have you looked at the `ADODB.Connection` for your transaction processing, and `ADODB.Command` for your parameterized queries? All the queries can be Sql Server stored procedures if that makes it easier.

Comment: *"Does using ADO and BeginTrans make the most sense for me?"* - It certainly sounds like a good place to start. Give it a try and let us know if you need further assistance.